# iPhone 5S with iOS 7.0.2 shrinks webview when keyboard is open

Tags: javascript, ios, css, ios7, webview

I have a simple form with text fields in my webview. In all the other iOS & iPhones, whenever the text fields gets focus and keyboard comes up, the webview nicely pushes the html up without any distortion. I don't even need to write any separate code for this. However, in iPhone 5S with iOS 7.0.2, the webview kind of shrinks the html, and triggers the landscape media query in my css, so my view gets into the landscape mode even if actually the phone is in portrait mode.
Is this a bug with this version of iOS or can there be a fix?
I even tried setting the height of the page as a fixed value, but that didn't solve this issue.